# error add a datatable row to another datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have datatable1 which has 11 columns and 100,000 rows.. I would like to do a check to see if the text in column one starts with "one" and if it does, add that row into the second datatable. I have done the below but yet still it does not work.. I get the error that the row belong to another table

```
foreach (DataRow r in queryDataTable.Rows)
{
     if (r[0].ToString().StartsWith(queryString))
     {
          dt.ImportRow(r);                    
     }
}
```

Comment: Mention exactly what error you getting and where?

Comment: Bt why r u not using Linq.. Instead of this forloop ..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your for loop, you may use LINQ to select those rows which StartsWith `queryString` and then you can use [CopytoDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) method to create a new table for the selected rows.

```
var NewTable = queryDataTable.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(r => r.Field<string>(0).StartsWith(queryString))
               .CopyToDataTable();
```

Remember to include `using System.Linq;` at the top.

Comment: will that return a datatble with all of the data

Comment: would new table be a datatable

Comment: can i select certain row in certain order doing this method if i know the indesedx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly import the row of one table into another datatable. You need to create a new row and then copy the row.

Try this -

```
dt.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray)
```